# "Breaking the symmetry" in solving a quartic equation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

I've heard somewhere a discussion about solving algebraic equations before:

- When solving a quadratic equation, we are essentially doing the following.  Observe that $\Bbb{C}(x,y)\supset\Bbb{C}(x+y,xy)$ and $x-y\not\in\Bbb{C}(x+y,xy)$. But $(x-y)^2\in \Bbb{C}(x+y,xy)$ and
  $$
  P_1(x,y)=x-y\in\Bbb{C}(x+y,xy,\sqrt{(x-y)^2})=\Bbb{C}(x,y,z).
  $$
- When solving a cubic equation, observe that
  $$
  \Bbb{C}(x,y,z)\supset\Bbb{C}(x+y+z,xy+yz+zx,xyz)
  $$
  and $P_1(x,y,z)=(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)\not\in \Bbb{C}(x+y+z,xy+yz+zx,xyz).$ Now
  $$
  [(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)]^2\in \Bbb{C}(x+y+z,xy+yz+zx,xyz)
  $$
  and
  $$
  (x-y)(y-z)(z-x)\in \Bbb{C}(x+y+z,xy+yz+zx,xyz,\sqrt{[(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)]^2}).
  $$
  The next step is to add $P_2(x,y,z)=x+\zeta y+\zeta^2 z$ to the field above to get $\Bbb{C}(x,y,z)$ where $\zeta^2+\zeta+1=0$.

Here are my **questions**:

> The pattern seems to be adding some special polynomials to the field generated by the elementary symmetric polynomials in symbols to get the filed generated by "singleton" of the symbols. How would one come up with a similar argument when solving a quartic equation? In what specific way is this procedure related to the group theory?

---

I learned only a little bit Galois theory in the modern approach by field theory before. One can have the [permutation group approach to Galois theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory#Permutation_group_approach_to_Galois_theory) according to the Wikipedia article. But I am not familiar with it.

Comment: Why not learn just a little bit more about Galois theory and permutations? They are needed to fully understand and formulate what is going on, and explaining why (and how) quartics can be solved but quintics cannot is a standard application of the theory that every good book will work out in detail.

Comment: Lagrange resolvents is the keyword.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: Thanks a lot for the information!

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen:  I should have noticed that one can continue that procedure at most up to the quartics but cannot for the quintics. Thanks for your suggestion!